# Initialized object becomes null in viewModel after button click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, castle-windsor

I am facing an issue in which object initialized using IoC (**CastleWindsor**) in **MainViewModel** becomes null as soon as I click a button on WPF form.

I have this code in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
var iocContainer = WindContainer.WindsorContainer;//This is IoCcontainer and working okay
  iocContainer.Install(new IoCInstaller());

 var mainWindowViewModel = iocContainer.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>("MainWindowViewModel");
 mainWindowViewModel.Initialize(iocContainer);
 DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
```

and the Initialize() method in MainWindowViewModel is as follows:

```
public void Initialize(WindsorContainer windsorContainer)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Initializing main view model");
            iocContainer = windsorContainer;
            myManager = iocContainer.Resolve<IMyManager>("MyManager");
            _dataManager = iocContainer.Resolve<IDataManager>("DataManager");
            _dataManager.Initialize();
         }
```

Everything works fine, but when I click a button and execute the command at that point iocContainer, _dataManager and myManager become null. Following code is also in MainWindowViewModel.

```
private ICommand _clickCommandForBttnA;
        public ICommand ClickCommandForBttnA
        {
            get
            {
                return _clickCommandForBttnA ?? (_clickCommandForBttnA = new CommandHandlerForBttnA(() => MyActionForBttnA(), _canExecute));
            }
        }

        public void MyActionForBttnA()
        {
            Logger.Debug("Option A is clicked");
            if (_dataManager.SomeData.Equals("myData"))//Here _dataManager is null after clicking button
            {
                BackgroundColorBttnA = Colors.Blue;
                BackgroundColorBttnB = _allButtonInitialColor;
                BackgroundColorBttnC = _allButtonInitialColor;
                BackgroundColorBttnD = _allButtonInitialColor;
                BackgroundColorBttnConfirm = _allButtonInitialColor;
            }
        }
```

Command Handler for the button

```
public class CommandHandlerForBttnA : ICommand
    {
        private Action _action;
        private bool _canExecute;
        public CommandHandlerForBttnA(Action action, bool canExecute)
        {
            _action = action;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }
    }
```

Any reason/suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: Either the ClickCommandForBttnA bound to the button is from an uninitialized MainWindowViewModel instance (in other words: an instance different from the one you create there in the code snippet from your MainWindow.xaml.cs); or something somewhere in your code sets _dataManager/myManager back to `null`. It is up to you to find out what is going on there. Review and analyze your code, and use the debugger to see what's going on in your program (set a breakpoint on the MainViewModel constructor and set breakpoints on any _dataManager / myManager assignments in your code...)

Comment: I agree with what @elgonzo said. To verify, you can turn _dataManager into a property with a backing field (keeping the name) and setting a breakpoint in the setter. If that is called, you stack will tell you where.

Comment: Are you sure that the view model instance executing the command is the same view model instance that was returned by CastleWindsor?  When resolving from an IoC container by name, you are not quite getting a singleton as you should be able to get another instance of said type with a different name.  Please add the code where you do the registration of MainViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with CastleWindsor library, but maybe my doubts will direct you to the solution.

I don't know and can't find in CastleWindsor documentation about:

`var iocContainer = WindContainer.WindsorContainer;//This is IoCcontainer and working okay`

Does it your code? Maybe something significant is hidden here?
I have a concern that the container could be disposed in time when you click button.

By the way - you are using DI in strange way. In my opinion you should not pass container to view model. View model should have the constructor with all dependencies as parameters. Then when you register dependencies in IoC container and next call Resolve for view model, then container will resolve object with all dependencies.